# Using eu.hansolo dependency in my JavaFX Project cause error running JUnit Tests

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, junit

I have these dependencies in my **JavaFX** project using **Maven** in **Intellij IDEA**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
    <version>17.1.15</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.hansolo.fx</groupId>
    <artifactId>countries</artifactId>
    <version>17.0.23</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.hansolo.fx</groupId>
    <artifactId>heatmap</artifactId>
    <version>17.0.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
    <artifactId>toolboxfx</artifactId>
    <version>17.0.33</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
    <artifactId>toolbox</artifactId>
    <version>17.0.33</version>
</dependency>
```

When I created Created **JUnit** Test classes and running that Test Classes the Running failed and display this error:

> java: error reading C:\Users\THE_USER.m2\repository\eu\hansolo\fx\countries\17.0.23\countries-17.0.23.jar; java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 68: file:/C:/Users/THE_USER/.m2/repository/eu/hansolo/fx/countries/17.0.23/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar

and

> java: error reading C:\Users\THE_USER.m2\repository\eu\hansolo\fx\heatmap\17.0.12\heatmap-17.0.12.jar; java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 66: file:/C:/Users/THE_USER/.m2/repository/eu/hansolo/fx/heatmap/17.0.12/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar

by removing these dependencies I could be able to run Test classes but I need these dependencies. How Could I solved it?

Comment: Show the relevant areas of your pom file ...becaue the error message implies there is something wrong `17.0.12/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar` ... not in the parts you have shown... ? please show full pom file...or an example project on github or alike...

Comment: @khmarbaise _or an example project on github or alike_ definitely not: all details of the problem (including resource, poms whatever files) __has to__ be here, external references simple don't exist (they are certain to wither away thus making them unavailable to future readers)

Answer (score 0):

There is somewhere duplication in dependencies in maven. I had many maven dependencies and I had the same error and I commented out one of dependency and the error disappeared. This code was some example code for somewhere.